# How can I replace img tag with embed tag onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace a image with a embed content when I hover over the image. I can replace image with image easily with below code but not easy with embed:

```
<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.jakesonline.org/black.gif'" alt="" />
```

The code replace a white image with a black image, test it here: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/html/testbed.html

But how can I replace a image with a embed swf using the same method as my above code, easy without any library like jquery ?

Example when I hover over this image http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif then it replace that image with

```
http://bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf - <embed src="http://www.bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf" />
```

Example (not work for sure, just my dream):

```
<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover=Replace("<embed src="http://www.bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf" />") />
```

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the innerHTML of a parent DOM:

```
<div id="thisOne">
  <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="doit(this.parentNode, '<embed src=\"http://www.jakesonline.org/black.swf\" height=\"240\" width =\"360\" />');" />
</div>

<script>
function doit(elem, theSrc) {
   elem.innerHTML = theSrc;
}
</script>
```

If you want it to switch back `onmouseout`, then write the function to toggle back and forth between `src`s, like:

```
<div id="thisOne" onmouseover="this.innerHTML='<embed src=&quot;http://www.jakesonline.org/black.swf&quot; height=&quot;240&quot; width =&quot;360&quot; /\>'" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='<img src=&quot;http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif&quot; />'" >
  <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Gave it a thumbs up! I ran out of ideas after I found out it as .swf :P And this seemed easy to understand

Comment: Thank you very much, are you have other method that work like:

     <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover=Replace("<embed src="http://www.bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf" width="200" height="300" />") />

It replace the whole img tag with that embed string(because embed tag sometimes need width and height attribute)

Thank you!

Comment: I tried:

  `<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="this.parentNode.innerHTML = '<embed src="bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf"; width="200" height="300" />';" />`

But don't work, seem some problem with my code...

Comment: I tried 

`<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="this.parentNode.innerHTML = '<embed src=http://bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf; width=200 height=200  />'" />`

Seem work but I have to remove double quote of src=, width= and height=, how can I include double quote in my code but still make it work ?

Thanks!

Comment: see edit.  You can send the whole embed tag, with H&W as string.

Comment: I mean it should be something like this:

`<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="this.parentNode.innerHTML = '<embed src="http://bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf"; width="200" height="200" />'" />`

Comment: Thank you, but can I treat whole <embed> tag as string of doit function that you provided ?, I mean I can use something like that to keep double quote original:
`<img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" onmouseover="doit(this.parentNode, '<embed src="http://www.jakesonline.org/black.swf" height="240" width ="360" />');" />`

Thank you, because I want to save a little time adding backslash to the double quote ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use CSS

See example (update):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        span.myClass {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 640px; /*Fix width, equals in <object> and <embed>*/
            height: 480px; /*Fix height*/
        }
        span.myClass object,
        span.myClass embed {
           display: none;
        }

        span.myClass:hover object,
        span.myClass:hover embed {
           display: block;
        }

        span.myClass:hover img {
           display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="myClass">
        <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/pc5/e8r/pc5e8rMcB.gif" alt="test...">

        <!--//Embed both Flash content and alternative content using standards compliant markup -->
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="640" height="480">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.bris.ac.uk/stemcells-msc/stemcells-msc/rolldice.swf" width="640" height="480">
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <p>Alternative content</p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```